# Building a DataFrame recursively in Python with pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

```
def recursive_df (n):
    if n==1:
        return pd.DataFrame({"A":[1],"B":[1]})
    if n>=2:
        return pd.concat(recursive_df(n-1),{"A":[n],"B":[n*n]} )
```

this is not working, and i can't see a reason "why" and what i should do about it ?

> TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you
> passed an object of type "DataFrame"

In practice, the real problem i want to solve is that i have created some dataframes as output of some function to store results, and i want to concatenate them.

for elegance, i want to avoid for loops

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a list in `concat` and to pass a `DataFrame`, not a dictionary:

```
def recursive_df (n):
    if n==1:
        return pd.DataFrame({"A":[1],"B":[1]})
    if n>=2:
        return pd.concat([recursive_df(n-1), pd.DataFrame({"A":[n],"B":[n*n]})])
```

Example:

```
recursive_df(2)
   A  B
0  1  1
0  2  4

recursive_df(3)
   A  B
0  1  1
0  2  4
0  3  9
```

Note that for this particular example you do not need recursion. A simple vectorized code will be much more efficient:

```
import numpy as np

def generate_df(n):
    s = np.arange(1, n+1)
    return pd.DataFrame({'A': s, 'B': s**2})

generate_df(3)
```

Comment: *NB. If really you need to concat, using a single `concat` is also much better: `pd.concat(list_of_dataframes])`*

Comment: thanks sorry for the stupid question

Comment: @Fagui it's not stupid ;)